# count if variable range vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement conditional formatting in VBA using a countif formula. It does work for the moment but I would like to implement a variable range. I have tried the following without success

```
 With Range("AI7").FormatConditions _
        .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(COUNTIF($C$7:$AG$7;""B"")<=3;COUNTIF($C$7:$AG$7;""R"")<=5)")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(185, 207, 203)
  End With
```

How to make the range within the countif dynamic. I have tried that:

```
With Range("AI7").FormatConditions _
        .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF(R[7]C[3], R[7]C[31])="B"")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(248, 194, 203)
    End With
```

Comment: *I would like to implement a variable range* - can you be more specific about this?

Comment: instead of writing C7:AG7 i would like to make AG dynamic, i.e. related to a variable. I tried the notation below but it does not seem to work

Comment: Try `Formula:="=COUNTIF($c$7:" & cells(r,c).Address & ";""B"")"` using r, and c as the row and column numbers of the last cell in your dynamic range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it. You'll have to grab the column letter(s) dynamically in whichever way you need, but you can put that into the `sCol` variable, below.

```
Dim sCol as String

 sCol = "AG" 'you'll have to define the column in whatever way you need

 With Range("AI7").FormatConditions _
        .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(COUNTIF($C$7:$" & sCol & "$7;""B"")<=3;COUNTIF($C$7:$" & sCol & "$7;""R"")<=5)")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(185, 207, 203)
  End With
```